# jqGrid toolbar filtering with a custom formatter

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, formatter

I've looked at the documentation for toolbar filtering, and in a couple of places I've needed to use a custom formatter in order to display images inside a cell.

With a custom formatter in place I don't get a toolbar filter is there anything I can do about this.

Comment: What do you mean under the "custom filter"? Which version of jqGrid you use? What information you want to display in the searching toolbar? Do you use local data filtering or the filtering on the server. A code example could make many things more clear.

Comment: I'm using a custom formatter do map a cellValue to an image that is then displayed in a grid cell. Ideally I'd like to put a dropdown list into the toolbar filter. The filtering is occuring server side.

Comment: Could you post the example of data saved in the cell? Do you display some values like 1,2,3 as red, yellow, green images in the custom formatter and want to display the values as texts in the dropdown list: "red", "yellow", "green"? If you write abstract "custom formatter" it can convert everything to everything. An example is much better.

Comment: Lol exactly as you describe in your example that's what I'm tying to achieve. I've got the images working just not the dropdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define  the `stype:'select'` and the `searchoptions` with the `value` or `dataUrl` for the column where you use the [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter):

```
stype:'select', searchoptions:{value:'...'}
```

then in the searching (including the [searching toolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching)) you will have dropdown list. So you can use your [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) to display the values **in the cells** and use standard select formatter in the [searching toolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching).

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithCustomFormatterAndFilterToolbar.htm):
[image]

Comment: Oleg, how can we filter @FedEx on page fist time load.

Comment: @Sudharshan: The answer depends on the value of `datatype` and `loadonce` parameters of the grid. Could you describe more detailed how you use jqGrid?